# Intensive work timetable

Tags: word-choice, present-continuous

In the context of a volunteering experience itemized in a CV, I would like to express the idea of waking up early everyday and working all the day long.

I wonder if one of the following phrases is correct.

- Intensive work timetable
- Intensive work schedule
- Intensive working timetable
- Intensive working schedule

Any other suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: **intensive** is not the ideal word here.  If we undergo *intensive* training in an area, for example, the training is very *thorough* and is undergone usually on an accelerated schedule. Your example just describes "long days".   If you are looking for the magic jargon that would cause your resume to be selected by a recruiter or by HR personnel, the question would be better asked on a site devoted to getting hired.

Comment: A correction of my attempt would be a great first step. I mean, can you explain how/why the word intensive is not appropriate?

Comment: Read my comment again. I did explain why.

Comment: (Maybe I didn't understand.) Are you saying that _intensive_ is not the ideal word because _working all the day long_ doesn't necessarily mean that a meticulous work was done? Btw what prompted me to write the preceding comment is that you used _intensive_ with an action (training), whereas I used it with an "object" (timetable/schedule), which makes me think that I misunderstood the meaning/collocation of the word _intensive_.

Comment: Your example did not talk about *meticulousness* at all. You mentioned waking up early and working all day. Were you working long days, days that began earlier and ended later than the typical work day? And if so, were you working those long days in order to complete something in a  foreshortened time period?

Comment: No, my example didn't talk about meticulousness. I'm just trying to understand your first comment (why _intensive_ is not the ideal word and which is the correct use of this word), otherwise I won't learn anything from this post. You wrote you explained it, I read it again, and there's still something missing in what *I understand* from it (my fault). By the way by _early_ I mean 5.00am; by _all the day long_ I mean going to sleep at 10.30pm; by the missing word (not _intensive_, as you're suggesting) I mean that I came back home physically exausted everyday.

Comment: Your job might have been *demanding* or *intense*, but to be *intensive* there has to some kind of immersive experience, where a great deal is accomplished in a relatively short time, in much less time than it would take in a  *normal* (non-intensive) situation. That is what I mean by "accelerated" in the second sentence of my first comment.

Comment: So intensive means "dense in time". Even if the job was not intensive it could have been intense or demanding. Can these two adjectives be used with "work timetable"?

Comment: **work timetable** refers to the completion of project tasks according to a schedule set in advance. *a demanding schedule* is commonly used to refer to frequent long days, possibly even work after hours at home and on the weekends.

Comment: So "demanding schedule" (is it superfluous "work" in between these two words?) seems to be what I was looking for. Can you add it as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*a demanding work schedule* is a phrase commonly used to describe a job where significantly more than the usual 9AM to 5PM commitment is expected from the employee.  Not that 9AM to 5PM isn't demanding.